# Image Upload in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, gallery, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload an image to my application. I'm using the following lines to achieve this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE);
```

But when opening gallery it shows me many folders such as "Recent Images", "Documents", "Google Drive" etc.,

Here instead showing like this I would like to show only the gallery folder. Can you please help me how I can achieve this?

Comment: If you're using a chooser, you are going to get all apps that can receive this intent.

Comment: That's actually quite normal, I do not know if you're able to have it if you proceed with intent... I would use a external library if you really want to have a lib but I wouldn't mind not having it...

Comment: Can you please mention the name of that lib... @LaurentMeyer

Comment: Something like: https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick but we'll have to work a bit on the style of it...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        PICK_IMAGE);
```